# private_pubを使用したリアルタイム通信について

Tags: ruby-on-rails

railsを使ったwebアプリでチャットのような機能を実装したいと思います。private_pubというgemをインストールしてコードを書いたのですが、うまく動かない状態です。

```
GET http://localhost:9292/faye.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

と表示されてしまい困っています。

```
http://mazeltov7.hateblo.jp/entry/2014/01/09/Private_pub%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6Rails4%E3%81%A7%E7%B0%A1%E5%8D%98%E3%81%AA%E3%83%81%E3%83%A3%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%82%A2%E3%83%97%E3%83%AA%E3%82%92%E4%BD%9C%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%BF
```

こちらのサイトを参考にしてコードを書きました。コードの間違いというよりはブラウザの問題なのか？と思っています。（コードが必要でしたらお手数ですがおっしゃっていただけたらと思います）

net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED というのはどういう意味なのでしょうか？どこに問題があるのか見当がつきそうでしたらご指摘いただけたらと思います。
何卒よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

`private pub` のサーバに繋がらない、という意味です。
`ps aux | grep private_pub` か何かで、サーバが起動しているか、確認してください。
可能性としては、`rackup private_pub.ru -s thin -E production` を忘れているのではないでしょうか？

## 追記

参考記事の github から clone してきて、インストールし、
ページを2つ開いて、片方に書けば、もう片方にも反映されます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: ありがとうございます！
rackup private_pub.ru -s thin -E production
を実行するとエラーがなくなりました！
しかし、ページが更新されません。。。
コンソールをみると、createアクションは問題なく実行されており、create.js.erbもrenderされているのですが、ページが変わりません。また、cssが　_message.html.erbに反映されないのですが、何が問題かわかりますでしょうか？？？

Comment: create.js.erb が render されている、というのはどのように確認されたのでしょうか？また、「cssが反映されない」というのは、どうなるはずだったのに、どうならなかった、のでしょうか？

Comment: お手数おかけします。もうしわけありません。IDEのコンソールをみるとRendered messages/create.js.erbと書かれています。またcssが反映されていないといいますのは _message.html.erbに対してcssが読み込まれないということです。もしよろしければ、こちらのリンク（stackoverflowの英語版です）にコードを書いているので見てもらえますか？何卒よろしくお願い致します　http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35055627/rails-private-pub-does-not-work

Comment: 545 pts/0    Sl+    0:00 ruby .bundle/binstubs/rackup private_pub.ru -s thin -E production
  574 pts/1    Sl+    0:01 /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.5/bin/ruby bin/rails s -b 0.0.0.0
サーバーは動いているようです。
私もクローンしたのですが、こちらも動きません。。。